# Not able to see newly added log in docker ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I'm using [sebp/elk](https://hub.docker.com/r/sebp/elk/)'s dockerised ELK. I've managed to get it running on my local machine and I'm trying to input dummy log data by SSH'ing into the docker container and running:

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash --path.data /tmp/logstash/data \
    -e 'input { stdin { } } output { elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost"] } }'
```

After typing in some random text, I cannot see it indexed by elasticsearch when I visit http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty&size=1000

Comment: can you provide your search query?

Comment: I'm literally searching for my dummy text, which is `this is a dummy entry`